# Paypal Sandbox - Cannot create buttons

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to create Paypal buttons in the Paypal Sandbox site. However, upon login, I see the old interface, and whenever I click on any of the links (ex : e-commerce solutions), it brings me back to the sandbox home page where the login button usually is (except the login button is replaced with "My account").

Basically, I log in to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com . The I click on the e-commerce solution link : https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=%5fmerchant&nav=3

This link redirects me to the sandbox home page.

Is the sandbox site broken?

P.S. Please note that my interface is in french, I don't know if this is the cause of my issue.

Comment: Link, please. We can't help if you don't give specifics.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my question and added the steps I made.

Answer (score 1):

According to PayPal, you have to do this for the SandBox to be fully functional.

> Create a set of virtual Sandbox test accounts.
> Format your PayPal API requests using the details from your test accounts and run them against the Sandbox endpoint(s).

Here're my best guesses as to what may be causing the issue.

#### Possible Problems

**1).** This is probably the actual cause- the sandbox might not support that link. Typically, when a link doesn't exist within a sandbox (or most sites, for that matter), it redirects to the homepage. In your case, the homepage will have the `My Account` tab, because you're already logged in.

**2).**

> "Please note that my interface is in french, I don't know if this is the cause of my issue"

I don't see how this would cause an issue, as long as you use `UTF-8`. Also, I don't believe the sandbox site is broken, as long as it's the PayPal site. If it's a sandbox page you made, that might be the case.

Comment: For #1 : That might be the case. I might have to contact Paypal for this I guess.